# How to insert fields from two models onto one form

Tags: php, yii

I have done everything like in this [example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/).

But I don't understand how to save the `id` fields to the related tables. I have two tables, company and entity, with one to one relations. It saves all the fields that I inserted, but not `company_id` and `entity_id`. Do I need to use aftersave?

In the Company controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model1=new Company;
    $model2=new Entity;
    if(isset($_POST['Company'], $_POST['Entity']))
    {
        // populate input data to $a and $b
        $model1->attributes=$_POST['Company'];
        $model2->attributes=$_POST['Entity'];

    // validate BOTH $a and $b
    $valid=$model1->validate();
    //$valid=$model2->validate() && $valid;

    if($valid)
    {
        // use false parameter to disable validation
        $model1->save(false);
        $model2->save(false);
        // ...redirect to another page
    }
}
$this->render('create', array(
    'model1'=>$model1,
    'model2'=>$model2,
));
}
```

In the Company model:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'entity'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Entity', 'entity_id')
    );
}
```

Comment: show what you have done

Comment: post the code that you have tried so far

Comment: As I understand I can add $model2->company_id = $model1->id;

Comment: if company_id is coming after saving company then you can try 

  $model1->save(false);
    $model2->company_id = $model1->id;
        $model2->save(false); . Then waht is issue in it?

Comment: I have field entity_id in table company, and don't have company_id in entity table

Comment: then saving entity first and then assign its id to company table like reverse of above. $model2->save(false); $model1->entity_id = $model2->id; $model1->save(false); As i understood......

Comment: I understand that I need to use 
$model2->save(false);
$model1->entity_id = $model2->id;
$model1->save(false);

Comment: Thanks a lot. now it's just to add update

Answer (score 2):

Ok, those are normal doubts when we begin playing with Yii. Let's see:

1. The "rules" method (in the models) should be only used to columns that are filled by the user. In your case, I guess "entity_id" is handled by the server, so remove it from "rules". With that new configuration, you can validate both objects before saving.
2. If validation succeeds, first save one model and use its "id" to save the other one that makes the reference. Something like that:

   ```
   public function actionCreate()
   {
       $model1=new Company;
       $model2=new Entity;

       if(isset($_POST['Company'], $_POST['Entity']))        
       {
           // populate input data to $a and $b
           $model1->attributes=$_POST['Company'];
           $model2->attributes=$_POST['Entity'];

           // validate BOTH $a and $b
           $valid=$model1->validate();
           $valid=$model2->validate() && $valid;

           if($valid)
           {
               $model2->save( );

               $model1->entity_id = $model2->id;
               $model1->save( );
           }
       }

       $this->render('create', array(
           'model1'=>$model1,
           'model2'=>$model2,
       ));
   }
   ```